# Reading integers from .dat file and collecting them in a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to read integers located in a dat file. I thought that this is the correct way to approach this problem but nothing prints out to the console and when I try to print out an index from vector  nothing shows up indicating that nothing is actually being store in the vector. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
 vector<int> nums;
 ifstream myfile;
 myfile.open("nums.dat");
 int a = 0;

 while (myfile >> a) {
     nums.push_back(a);
 }



 for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
     cout << nums.at(i) << endl;
 }





 return 0;
```

Comment: What is the actual format of the file?  The `.dat` extension usually implies binary data. If so, you can't use `operator>>` to read binary data (well, there are ways you can, but not in this example), you will have to open the file with the `std::ifstream::binary` flag enabled and then use [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) for the reading, eg: `myfile.open("nums.dat", std::ifstream::binary); while (myfile.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a))) { ... }`

Comment: show us nums.dat and add `if( !myfile.good() ) { cerr << "cannot open/read \"nums.dat\""}` statement as well